# usb_cam ros kinetic on raspberry pi 3 B

Tags: ros-kinetic, usb-cam, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
My Raspicam v1 is not working on Raspberry pi B. I tried various methods to start it with command raspistill -v -o img.jpg and also with raspicam_node package of ROS, but still it did not show any success.
I have Logitech camera. So can I use usb_cam package of ROS on Raspberry Pi 3 B.
ROS Version : Kinetic
Raspberry Pi version: Raspberry Pi 3 B

Thanks & Regards,
Rutuja Haridas

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/331620/usb_cam-ros-kinetic-on-raspberry-pi-3-b/) by [rutujaharidas](https://answers.ros.org/users/44034/rutujaharidas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-08-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it an official rapi cam or one with interchangeable lens? Did you activate the camera support with raspi-config?

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2019-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rutujaharidas](https://answers.ros.org/users/44034/rutujaharidas/) on 2019-09-08**:
It is an official raspi cam. It does not have interchangeable lens.
And I have activated the camera with raspi-config.
Still I am not able to connect the raspi camera. It shows camera is not connected while capturing the images with command raspistill -v -o img.jpg.

Thanks & Regards,
Rutuja Haridas

**Comment by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) on 2019-09-09**:
Did you check the orientation of the fpc on both sides. Or maybe your module is damaged. Does the gpu have enough Ram

**Comment by [rutujaharidas](https://answers.ros.org/users/44034/rutujaharidas/) on 2019-09-14**:
Hi,
I have no idea that if the camera module is damaged or not because when I connect the  raspi camera module it with Raspberry Pi the light on camera is on.

Thanks & Regards,
Rutuja Haridas